# Mototrbo - cannot correctly terminate the call

Tags: motorola

We are building communication system where mototrbo platform is used. We are developing the application client which can initiate individual and group calls. We have some issue related to the individual call when close call. During the call we have a lot of request/replies I will note about request related to call termination. We send the following termination request:

```
Sending message: *xcmp.CallCtrlRequest{
   "Opcode": "CALL_CTRL_REQ",
   "Function": "Terminate",
   "CallType": "EnhancedPrivateCall",
   "RmtAddr": {
      "AdressType": 1,
      "Size": 3,
      "RmtAddr": "AWN4",
      "Port": 0
   },
   "GroupId": {
      "Size": 0,
      "GroupId": [
         0,
         0,
         0
      ]
   },
   "RmtAddr2": {
      "AdressType": 0,
      "Size": 0,
      "RmtAddr": null,
      "Port": 0
   }
}
```

In response we receive:

```
Messgae received: *xcmp.CallCtrlReply{
   "Opcode": "CALL_CTRL_REPLY",
   "Result": "IncorrectMode",
   "Function": "Terminate",
   "State": "CallNoStatus"
}
```

Replay returns error IncorrectMode". In our system we use call type EnhancedPrivateCall and Direct Call mode.
I guess issue is related to call type or/and used mode because according to specification(2.17 and 2.41) these settings are supported for Connect Plus mode and for devices Private Phone Call,
Group Phone Call.
Then I don't understand how to terminate call in my configuration. Please explain me how to fix this issue.